# Multi-Account API Gateway Integration with Private API Gateways in different VPCs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

We have two AWS Accounts with bunch of private API Gateways (backed by lambda, cognito etc). We would like to access these api gateway via public one (via proxy feature of api gateway). I have done integration with public ones without any issue. But now we would like to these setup.

[image]

What would be the best approach here ?

We would like to keep cost minimum. I have shown only important components here for simplicity.

Comment: Interesting setup. However, I wonder how do you decide if a request to the public API should be routed to the private API in account A or account B?  Are they going to be two different type of requests?

Comment: public api gateway has proxy resource integration: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html

Comment: First, you have to create a VPC Link proxy integration for your public API that allows you to connect to one private API in the VPC. But the thing is, if you are to have two different private APIs in different VPCs (and accounts), it may be tricky since a VPC Link integration can be associated with only one VPC. You cannot have two VPC links associated with one API nor can you use one VPC link to point to two different VPCs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good article in Medium (https://medium.com/@nate_mitchell/api-gateway-as-an-inter-vpc-private-api-proxy-3c29b67e91ee) describing the process. It describes using VPC endpoints to route the traffic internally. I think what you are missing in your diagram is a network load balancer to balance between the API Gateways.

Comment: NLB target groups can not target API Gateway